# why am I getting None value while reverse geocoding when geocoding gave me the exact same latitudes and longitude?

Tags: python, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I'm trying to use reverse geocoding to try and find the state and city. But I am not getting any results for certain latitudes and longitudes. Given below is an example of Adams State University in Colorado. I used the Institute name and State name to get the Lat and Long. But when I use the same Lat and Long to reverse geocode the same I get None as the result. If I'm using the same Nominatim(user_agent="MyApp") for both why is this happening and what should I do?

```
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="MyApp")

location = geolocator.geocode("Adams State University, Colorado")
Lat = location.latitude
Long = location.longitude
print('LAT: ',location.latitude)
print('LONG:', location.longitude)


LAT:  37.47480245
LONG: -105.8819230946304
```

```
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="MyApp")

location = geolocator.reverse("37.474802,-105.881923")
state = location.raw.get('address').get('State')
city = location.raw.get('address').get('City')
print('State: ',state)
print('City: ',city)


State:  None
City:  None
```

Comment: `get()` on a dictionary returns `None` if it can't get the requested key. I'd look there first.

Comment: Try `print(location.raw)` to see what the reverse geocoder is returning.